# How to set ios constraints dependent on label rows

Tags: ios, constraints

i have a UITableViewCell with a label, textview and an icon bar.

All the components are stacked vertical, the label take up 10% of the height, the textview 80% and the icon bar 10%. The data is fetched from an API.

If i get a header that will require 2 lines in the label i would need to make the textview smaller. Is it possible to do this with constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

1. Set your `UITableViewCell` height for example to 100. (easier to
   understand)
2. Set `left`, `right`, `bottom` constraints to `superview` for icon bar to 0 and height constraint to 10. (10%)
3. Set `left`, `right`, `top` constraints to `superview` for label to 0. Don't set height constraint it will be calculated automatically from text or set it with Relation as Greater Than or Equal (it is like min-height). Set 0 lines for multiline.
4. Set `UITextView`'s `left` and `right` to `superview` to 0, `bottom` to icon bar as 0, `top` to label as 0.

Now when you will have 2 lines for label height of `UITextView` will be smaller.